# squeaking and rumbling pipes

Tags: water

Hi. I need to create the sound of squeaking pipes with a rumbling noise. Basically a character turns a water tap and the pipes squeak then there is a rumble and finally some dirty water splashes out into the sink. Any ideas where to begin?

Answer (score 2):

Rarely are the sounds we hear in a film, the sounds we think we are hearing. In other words, you don't need to have access to old squeaky water pipes. You will have to create the desired sounds by layering numerous different textures until you achieve the required effect. Try recording all the metal tools you can find (i.e. wrenches, chisels etc.). [Ikea sell very cheap table legs](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10105290) that can be tapped, knocked etc. They resonate pretty well. For the squeakiness, try getting hold of some old rusty hinges (again, raiding your own or someone else's garage may work out). If you know of any squeaky doors, this can also be useful.

At the end of the day, you'll have to just get pretty experimental. Record as much source material as possible. Also don't forget to record from different perspectives as this'll give you very different results. And then start layering your sounds together to try to build something that will be perceived by the unsuspecting audience that they are in fact hearing squeaky pipes. For your rumble, there are many sources that can be recorded in the home that with a bit of editing can produce some great results. Somewhere I saw a video tutorial on this with a garage door being recorded and turned into a low rumble. Can't remember exactly where I saw it but I'll edit the post and add a link if I remember.

EDIT:
Here's the video on making impact sounds:

[youtube]IMgovfQjxUA[/youtube]

Comment: Thanks so much for a direction to explore. This forum has been an excellent source of information already - and I've only known about it for a day!

Answer (score 2):

Liberal use of Altiverb may help you…there are impulse responses of metal pipes, tanks and containers that could transform a dry pipe rattle recording into something much fuller and deeper, with some convincing depth and size.

Comment: @Jay Nice idea! Didn't think of impulse reverbs. Just booted up Logic's Space Designer and there are some nice pipe-related presets in there too. Good call!

Answer (score 1):

no idea how to record this, but an early scene of the book of eli has a great rendition of it to study.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The opening of Delicatessen starts with a twisted ambient pipe sequence.

Comment: Yes, a great movie - The 'sex' scene is one of the best bits of sound design that I am aware of. Type in 'Delicatessen sex scene' in You tube - fantastic. (or buy the movie!)